# Check that a value on a webpage is numerical in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

When checking to see if a price is given on a webpage, I don't want to check the exact value (as that's subject to change), I first want to check that the page object exists (no error, etc.) and then that it's returning a numerical value.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you share more details. which languages do you use? what did you try? it is a very general question.

Comment: you can get text of element and check it is numerical or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is a numeric type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C#

```
private IWebElement priceElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("price_value"));

public bool PriceObjectValidation()
{
    decimal outDecim;

    try
    {
        string str = priceElement.Text;
        bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(str, out outDecim);

        return isDecimal;

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Price element is not found");
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your Test Script you can use

```
Assert.True(PriceObjectValidation(), "Price element is not numeric value");
```